# can you drop a table in sql server while it is being used in another session in a select statement?

Tags: sql-server

can you drop a table in sql server while it is being used in another session in a select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are running long select query there is Schema Stability Lock involved(`SCH-S`) which protects the object(table) from being dropped.

Comment: once the lock drops, though, the table will be dropped, won't it? The `DROP TABLE` may have to wait in line, but is should eventually execute.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yes, the query will be blocked and will wait until the long SELECT is finished. After that the session that executed DROP TABLE will remove the table